# Regular actions in English (past simple/cont/would/context)

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> I was depressed for a month. When I was trying to beat my depression, **I went to the cinema, I spent time outside, I learned new skills and worked out**

I want the 4 actions in bold to sound as if they were regular/repetitive.

1. Does the sentence sound natural without any changes?
2. Should I use the Past Continuous to express the idea of repeated actions in the past that is not true today? ("I was going/learning/spending")?
3. Is "would" more appropriate? (**I'd go to the cinema, I'd spend time outside, I'd learn new skills"**) to stress the regular
   nature of these actions in the past?

I was told by teachers that "would" is only used for big periods of time and habitual actions, so I am not sure if it'll work with a 1-month period.

Comment: This site is not for getting writing help or proofreading. If there is one aspect of English you would like help with, please edit your question to be about that one aspect. If there are multiple aspects of English you need to ask about to complete your task, then please ask several different questions, with each one clearly about one aspect of English. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I honestly believed It would be better to ask all questions in the same post since they are more or less related to the same topic. I thought I'd have my reputation lowered if I started making too many posts.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial sentence is absolutely fine.

None of the others ideas are an improvement, but if you want to introduce would it would be OK if you wrote the sentence as "I'd go to the cinema, spend time outside, and learn new skills. Repeating "I'd" is unnecessary, but not wrong.

The second example is fine, too.

Comment: thank you! Is it possible to use "would" if there is only 1 action, not a succession of actions, as in 
"When I was fighting depression, I'd go to the cinema"

Comment: @Mr.PastProgressive Yes, that's perfectly acceptable. "When I had" makes what follows conditional on what you had.

Comment: Just to let you know, I edited the question and removed the OP's 2nd example to facilitate its reopening.